# Configuration for IPV6 in WiFi network

Tags: wifi, ubuntu-12.04, ipv6

IPV6 was setup on local Ethernet network,is it the same method to be used for WiFi. also WiFi IPV6 has any dependency on wifi adapter.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. However, this is not the right place to ask it. You will probably have more success on superuser.com, another site of the Stack Exchange network. And to be honest: there is not much to answer your question: WiFi is a wireless extension of an ethernet, so if it works on ethernet then WiFi should also just work (unless you have any weird filtering on the Wifi)

Answer (score 0):

No, the *Wi-Fi stack* operate on the data and physical link layer **only**. Moreover IPv6 operate on the network layer.

[image: 802.11 OSI model]

So at this level there is no difference between Wi-Fi and Ethernet.

Comment: So can we use libcrafter for IPV6 discovery just as the way we do for IPV4